# How can I log new websockets connection requests to Phoenix?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I am running a new Phoenix Liveview app on a kubernetes cluster made available to me, and while HTTP works fine, my websockets connections are failing. Even though the request has the header asking to upgrade the connection, I get back a `426 Upgrade Required`. I suspect that part of the route between my browser and Phoenix is removing the `Upgrade` header, but I want to know for sure if this is the case.

I already tried adding a simple plug in my Endpoint to log connections, and it works for the regular HTTP requests, but doesn't intercept the websockets requests. Is there somewhere else I need to be putting the plug or adding some logging to dump these requests (specifically, their headers) that are asking to be upgraded to websockets connections?

Comment: if you are using something like nginx in reverse proxy mode, you should explicitly allow upgrade requests when configuring nginx.

Comment: Thanks @Daniel, I'll pass it on to the people running the kubernetes cluster to see if they have that set up on their side.